# How to sort large data in Java?

Tags: java

I have created a project in Java called Music and there is a file called music.txt within the NetbeansProjects, I would like to sort all the data, for example, the  singer, song name, year, duration in minutes, and genre into the Music project.

I have used collections.sort, however for that I have copied and pasted all the data and wrote:

```
list.add(new Music("Justin Timberlake", "Cry me a river", 2003, 4, "Pop")
list.add(new Music("Mariah Carey", "One sweet day", 1996, 2, "R&B")
```

#### And then

```
collections.sort(list);
```

then used a for loop, as the list is less than i, i will be incremented each time.

but there are about 600 lines of Music, is there a faster way to sort the music in alphabetical order, as well as the year being from oldest-newest? I am a beginner at Java, hence just a bit confused.

Comment: You have loaded the content, added it to a list and sorted it. Looks like you are done. What is the question and/or what is the problem? Please edit your question to include the source code you have and the problem/question you have.

Comment: The code works, but I was wondering if there was a faster method to sort the list? Maybe reading the file from music.txt, if possible?

Comment: You are not reading the content of the file with java but instead write the `list.add(new Music(...));` lines by yourself (in this case having 600 lines like that)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java provides the method Collection.sort(...) because it is efficient! If you want to choose a sorting criteria, you should have to implement a comparator or a comparation criterion.
You can do this in two ways:

The first one is to add a method "compareTo" in your Music class.

```
public int compareTo(Contact other) {
    return name.compareTo(other.name); //for example...
}
```

and so call `Collections.sort(list)`.

Now the second one: you can define an external controllable ordering:

```
// Now sort by year instead of name (default).
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Music>() {
    public int compare(Music one, Music two) {
        return one.getYear().compareTo(two.getYear());
    }
});
```

After that, your list will be sorted by name or year and you can get all the Music objects in order.

For example:

```
list.add(new Music("Justin Timberlake", "Cry me a river", 2003, 4, "Pop")
list.add(new Music("Mariah Carey", "One sweet day", 1996, 2, "R&B")

//sorting list
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Music>() {
    public int compare(Music one, Music two) {
        return one.getYear().compareTo(two.getYear()); //by year
    }
});

//now see the result
for(Music m: list)
    System.out.println(m.toString());
```

Your output will be

> ["Mariah Carey", "One sweet day", 1996, 2, "R&B"]
>
> ["Justin Timberlake", "Cry me a river", 2003, 4, "Pop"]

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful! Just a quick question about the compareTo method, would this method be located after declaring the variables,                                          
 in the class public Music implements Comparable <Music>                                   
  { public int(compareTo...}

Comment: You must add to your Music class declaration `implements Comparable<Music>`, so you can override the "compareTo" method: `@Override
public int compareTo(Music other) {
    /...
}`

Comment: Its position in the code is not important. Java don't throws any error if you put a method before o after the variables declaration (as it happens instead in python, for example). Be sure to implements "Comparable" and override the method "compareTo".

Answer (score 0):

You can sort simply by using the Java standard class library. The methods are very efficient and 600 is not a large number. So try something like this:

```
List<Music> list = ...;
list.sort(comparing(Music::getName);
```

This sorts by name.

Or for fist sorting by name an then (in case of equal names) on year:

```
list.sort(comparing(Music::getName).thenComparing(Music::getYear));
```

Method `comparing` is a static import from class `java.util.Comparator`.